# MultiMC crashing once it completes loading 7/7

Tags: java, crash, minecraft

MultiMC crashes whenever it finishes loading, no red message stating why, here's the crash report

---- Minecraft Crash Report ----

WARNING: coremods are present:
  llibrary (llibrary-core-1.0.11-1.12.2.jar)
  LoadingPlugin (HardcoreDarkness-MC1.12.2-2.0 (1).jar)
  Quark Plugin (Quark-r1.6-177.jar)
  IvToolkit (IvToolkit-1.3.3-1.12.jar)
  DynamicSurroundingsCore (DynamicSurroundings-core-1.12.2-3.5.4.3.jar)
  DLFMLCorePlugin (DynamicLights-1.12.2.jar)
Contact their authors BEFORE contacting forge

// I let you down. Sorry :(

Time: 1/21/20 11:23 AM
Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail

net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderExceptionModCrash: Caught exception from §3Dynamic Surroundings (dsurround)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.orecruncher.lib.expression.Expression.eval()Lorg/orecruncher/lib/expression/Variant;
    at org.orecruncher.dsurround.registry.biome.BiomeMatcher$ConditionsImpl.match(BiomeMatcher.java:275)
    at org.orecruncher.dsurround.registry.biome.BiomeRegistry.lambda$null$2(BiomeRegistry.java:143)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.orecruncher.dsurround.registry.biome.BiomeRegistry.lambda$init$4(BiomeRegistry.java:143)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.orecruncher.dsurround.registry.biome.BiomeRegistry.init(BiomeRegistry.java:141)
    at org.orecruncher.dsurround.registry.Registry.initialize(Registry.java:95)
    at org.orecruncher.dsurround.registry.RegistryManager.lambda$load$1(RegistryManager.java:143)
    at org.orecruncher.lib.collections.ObjectArray.forEach(ObjectArray.java:92)
    at org.orecruncher.dsurround.registry.RegistryManager.load(RegistryManager.java:143)
    at org.orecruncher.dsurround.registry.RegistryManager.initialize(RegistryManager.java:114)
    at org.orecruncher.dsurround.proxy.Proxy.loadCompleted(Proxy.java:100)
    at org.orecruncher.dsurround.ModBase.loadCompleted(ModBase.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:637)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:219)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:136)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.initializeMods(Loader.java:757)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.finishMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:336)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:535)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:378)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launchWithMainClass(OneSixLauncher.java:196)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launch(OneSixLauncher.java:231)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.listen(EntryPoint.java:143)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:34)

### A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_221, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 1142426392 bytes (1089 MB) / 3352297472 bytes (3197 MB) up to 7635730432 bytes (7282 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xms512m -Xmx8192m
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP 9.42 Powered by Forge 14.23.5.2847 38 mods loaded, 38 mods active
    States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored

```
| State  | ID                          | Version           | Source                                        | Signature                                |
|:------ |:--------------------------- |:----------------- |:--------------------------------------------- |:---------------------------------------- |
| LCHIJA | minecraft                   | 1.12.2            | minecraft.jar                                 | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | mcp                         | 9.42              | minecraft.jar                                 | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | FML                         | 8.0.99.99         | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2847-universal.jar       | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | forge                       | 14.23.5.2847      | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2847-universal.jar       | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | ivtoolkit                   | 1.3.3-1.12        | minecraft.jar                                 | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | dsurroundcore               | 3.5.4.3           | minecraft.jar                                 | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | aether_legacy               | 1.4.4             | aether_legacy-1.12.2-v1.4.4.jar               | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | jei                         | 4.15.0.293        | jei_1.12.2-4.15.0.293.jar                     | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | quark                       | r1.6-177          | Quark-r1.6-177.jar                            | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | autoreglib                  | 1.3-32            | AutoRegLib-1.3-32.jar                         | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | battletowers                | 1.6.5             | BattleTowers-1.12.2.jar                       | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | bettercaves                 | 1.12.2            | bettercaves-1.12.2-1.6.0.jar                  | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | dynamiclights               | 1.4.9             | DynamicLights-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | dynamiclights_onfire        | 1.0.7             | DynamicLights-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | dynamiclights_creepers      | 1.0.6             | DynamicLights-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | dynamiclights_dropitems     | 1.1.0             | DynamicLights-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | dynamiclights_entityclasses | 1.0.1             | DynamicLights-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | dynamiclights_mobequipment  | 1.1.0             | DynamicLights-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | dynamiclights_flamearrows   | 1.0.1             | DynamicLights-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | dynamiclights_floodlights   | 1.0.3             | DynamicLights-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | dynamiclights_otherplayers  | 1.0.9             | DynamicLights-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | dynamiclights_theplayer     | 1.1.3             | DynamicLights-1.12.2.jar                      | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | hardcoredarkness            | 2.0               | HardcoreDarkness-MC1.12.2-2.0 (1).jar         | d72e0dd57935b3e9476212aea0c0df352dd76291 |
| LCHIJA | llibrary                    | 1.7.19            | llibrary-1.7.19-1.12.2.jar                    | b9f30a813bee3b9dd5652c460310cfcd54f6b7ec |
| LCHIJA | iceandfire                  | 1.7.0             | Ice-and-Fire-Mod-1.12.2.jar                   | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | libraryex                   | 1.0.12            | LibraryEx-1.12.2-1.0.12.jar                   | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | mantle                      | 1.12-1.3.3.55     | Mantle-1.12-1.3.3.55 (1).jar                  | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | mowziesmobs                 | 1.5.4             | mowziesmobs-1.5.4.jar                         | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | netherex                    | 2.0.15            | NetherEx-1.12.2-2.0.15.jar                    | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | reccomplex                  | 1.4.8.2           | RecurrentComplex-1.4.8.2.jar                  | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | roguelike                   | 1.8.0             | RoguelikeDungeons-1.12.2-1.8.0.jar            | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | soundfilters                | 0.11_for_1.12     | SoundFilters-0.11_for_1.12.jar                | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | twilightforest              | 3.10.1013         | twilightforest-1.12.2-3.10.1013-universal.jar | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | tconstruct                  | 1.12.2-2.13.0.171 | TConstruct-1.12.2-2.13.0.171.jar              | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | tetra                       | 0.39.1            | tetra-1.12.2-0.39.1.jar                       | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | traverse                    | 1.6.0             | Traverse-1.12.2-1.6.0-69.jar                  | None                                     |
| LCHIJA | orelib                      | 3.6.0.1           | OreLib-1.12.2-3.6.0.1.jar                     | 7a2128d395ad96ceb9d9030fbd41d035b435753a |
| LCHIJE | dsurround                   | 3.5.4.3           | Dynamic-Surroundings-Mod-1.12.2.jar           | 7a2128d395ad96ceb9d9030fbd41d035b435753a |

Loaded coremods (and transformers):
```

llibrary (llibrary-core-1.0.11-1.12.2.jar)
  net.ilexiconn.llibrary.server.core.plugin.LLibraryTransformer
  net.ilexiconn.llibrary.server.core.patcher.LLibraryRuntimePatcher
LoadingPlugin (HardcoreDarkness-MC1.12.2-2.0 (1).jar)
  lumien.hardcoredarkness.asm.ClassTransformer
Quark Plugin (Quark-r1.6-177.jar)
  vazkii.quark.base.asm.ClassTransformer
IvToolkit (IvToolkit-1.3.3-1.12.jar)

DynamicSurroundingsCore (DynamicSurroundings-core-1.12.2-3.5.4.3.jar)
  org.orecruncher.dsurround.asm.Transformer
DLFMLCorePlugin (DynamicLights-1.12.2.jar)
  atomicstryker.dynamiclights.common.DLTransformer
    GL info: ' Vendor: 'NVIDIA Corporation' Version: '4.6.0 NVIDIA 391.25' Renderer: 'GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2'
    Pulsar/tconstruct loaded Pulses: 
        - TinkerCommons (Enabled/Forced)
        - TinkerWorld (Enabled/Not Forced)
        - TinkerTools (Enabled/Not Forced)
        - TinkerHarvestTools (Enabled/Forced)
        - TinkerMeleeWeapons (Enabled/Forced)
        - TinkerRangedWeapons (Enabled/Forced)
        - TinkerModifiers (Enabled/Forced)
        - TinkerSmeltery (Enabled/Not Forced)
        - TinkerGadgets (Enabled/Not Forced)
        - TinkerOredict (Enabled/Forced)
        - TinkerIntegration (Enabled/Forced)
        - TinkerFluids (Enabled/Forced)
        - TinkerMaterials (Enabled/Forced)
        - TinkerModelRegister (Enabled/Forced)
        - quarkIntegration (Enabled/Not Forced)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Surroundings 3.5.4.3 is old enough that it still calls methods from OreLib on a class that [has since had them removed](https://github.com/OreCruncher/OreLib/commit/17e2163a005ee812647f6e14d323d1eafcee2e53#diff-be11f73e04c82b56bfe34ac5b53da616L63-L67). To fix it, update Dynamic Surroundings to version 3.6.0.2.